# Size of SPF with other TXT records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, spf

The [SPF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208) says:

> The published SPF record for a given domain name SHOULD remain
> small    enough that the results of a query for it will fit within 512
> octets.    Otherwise, there is a possibility of exceeding a DNS
> protocol limit.
>
> …
>
> Note that when computing the sizes for replies to queries of the
> TXT    format, one has to take into account any other TXT records
> published    at the domain name.

It also points out that more recent DNS specifications allow for larger UDP responses (the reason for the limitation, as the SPF spec implies you should not rely on DNS over TCP working), but that doesn't really seem to override the "SHOULD".

The problem is that so many organizations require TXT records on the same domain for verification purposes (things like `facebook-domain-verification`, `google-site-verification`, `atlassian-domain-verification`, `adobe-sign-verification`, etc.) and can quickly pump the size of the total TXT RRset well over 512 bytes.

It looks like the majority of big organizations are complying with this, but there are a few that go over:

```
% dig +noall +stats netflix.com TXT | grep 'MSG SIZE'
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 593

% dig +noall +stats linkedin.com TXT | grep 'MSG SIZE'
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 632

% dig +noall +stats twitter.com TXT | grep 'MSG SIZE'
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 642

% dig +noall +stats microsoft.com TXT | grep 'MSG SIZE'
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 1459
```

(You can see the potential truncation happening by running something like `dig +notcp +noedns +ignore microsoft.com TXT`.)

I've been right up against the edge for six months, and now I need to add another verification record for a new vendor that will push me well past 512 bytes. I've done as much as I can to consolidate my SPF record, and I've made sure that I can't remove existing verification records.

What should I do here? I can't not have the verification records, but I don't want to ignore the SPF spec, either.  That said, Microsoft seems to be ignoring it, and I don't think they're getting their mail rejected.

Comment: I'm assuming you've made good use of the `include` or `redirect` functions?

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, SPF also dictates no more than 10 total DNS requests, and we have a number of `include`s to other vendors who send email on our behalf, and they also have their own `include`s, so I'm at the absolute limit there. (And hoping that those vendors don't add any new ones.)

Comment: Normally "verification" records may be needed just once, at the verification step and not later. It can be a burden to add/remove them on purpose, but maybe you do not need all of them all the time.

Comment: BTW your use case totally shows the error of having SPF using a TXT record instead its own SPF record type as planned at the beginning, and the fact of anchoring it at root, where under a `_spf` label it would have been fine.

Comment: "Normally" a well behaved client retries over TCP if the answer came truncated over UDP. And/or uses the EDNS0 extension to signal a larger buffer size for UDP. There are nameservers broken in both of these points so indeed for those your TXT recordset being "too" large would make them not working, but for all other nameservers implementing the DNS specification properly, your setup will work, with at worst an extra delay (retry over TCP for example)

Comment: "I've made sure that I can't remove existing verification records." maybe you can move them to a subdomain?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've checked with all of the vendors and they all say that they periodically recheck the verification, and that they don't have an alternate verification method, so I can't remove them.  I also agree that using TXT records is absurd, especially since they went to the effort of creating a new DNS RRtype and then abandoned it. Also, vendors should allow for verification TXT records being on different names than the root. Sounds like your advice is "just violate the SHOULD in the RFC because you have no other recourse".

Comment: Technically you are not violating anything. The RFC uses "SHOULD" which is formerly defined as "This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course." I believe your analysis of the problem completely respects the "full implications must be understood and carefully weighed", and based on my understanding of your constraints I personally see no real other solutions (than going over 512 octets)

Comment: Looks like I latched onto a misreading of the RFC where I thought it explicitly disallowed DNS over TCP, but it actually seems to just be trying to avoid situations where DNS over TCP might not work. (Brokenness.) My initial concern was that, for TXT RRset sizes over 512B, DNS clients had to support EDNS; now it's that they have to either support EDNS or DNS over TCP.  I'm much more comfortable with that.

Comment: "I thought it explicitly disallowed DNS over TCP" That would have been going right against the DNS standard so, no, no one is allowed to disallow DNS over TCP :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading the SPF spec, the concern about the TXT RRset size is that DNS responses could be truncated if the client *both* does not support EDNS *and* the client does not support DNS over TCP. DNS over TCP has always been a required part of DNS, and the caveat seems to be concerned with broken DNS. (To be fair, there have been a lot of places where DNS over TCP was broken, especially in the past.)

But I know that my DNS servers are accessible via TCP, and I'm far less concerned with other people's actively broken DNS than I am with ensuring that they support a (relatively) new DNS spec.

So the answer seems to be that I have ["valid reasons … to ignore [the] item, [and] the full implications [have been] understood and carefully weighed"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119).